# Get sheet's ordinal number in Excel

Tags: excel

What function or formula should I use to get an ordinal number of a sheet?

For example, if I have two sheets named "foo" and "bar", the function `get_sheet_num()` should return 1 when called from "foo" and 2 when called from "bar"

Comment: Do you mean it should return 2 when called from "bar"?  If so, and you're planning on using the function in a worksheet formula, then Richard Morgan's answer should be exactly what you need.

Comment: sorry for the error, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will properly return worksheet index:

```
Public Function get_sheet_num() As Long
    get_sheet_num = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Index
End Function
```